# How to load model after saving only with torch.save(model)?

Tags: python, neural-network, torch

I just trained a model based on the T5 network, but I managed to save it only with

```py
torch.save(model, 'trained_model')
```

Which saved the model in a single `trained_model` file.

When I now try to load it with

```py
model = torch.load("trained_model")
```

I get an error of `No module named 'transformers.modeling_t5'`

Or with this:

```py
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("trained_model")
```

I get an error of `It looks like the config file at 'trained_model' is not a valid JSON file.`

Is there any way to recover the model without retraining it?

EDIT

to train the model I used a script in which:

1. I loaded the raw T5 model

```py
raw_model = 'rut5-base-multitask'
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(raw_model).cuda()
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(raw_model)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
```

2. Trained the model
3. Saved the model

```py
torch.save(model, 'trained_model')
```

4. Tested the model with `model.eval()`

Answer (score 0):

try this for saving the model

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

and for load that model again

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

there other way to do that you can find in [this article](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-state-dict-recommended)

Comment: I, stupidly, did not use a notebook for this project, so there is no way for me to save the model without retraining the whole thing. Is there any other way?

Comment: no, the model is trained and saved in a separate script

Comment: which program did you use to run the training process?

Comment: check the edit on the post